# Logout from Google account also logs out from my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, google-authentication

I am using Google authentication to validate the identity and privileges of the user on my site.

I have no problem in redirecting the user when they visit a site to the google login webpage is they are not authenticated but I'm having problems when the user signs out from his google account from another tab.

How can I implement a system in which, if the authenticated user signs out of his google account from outside my application after he validated from within; my site will recognize the process and redirect the user to the log in page once again?

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Read paragraph #3 that is my question. In short I need to redirect user to Login page of my app if he logged out from Google Account.

Comment: It's like you have youtube.com open in tab-1, gmail.com open in tab-2 and myapp open in tab-3 all three using google account for login now if user logs out from gmail.com tab-2 and goes to youtube.com on tab-1 refresh that youtube.com will also log him out as he used same google account for logging, now youtube which is also google app but using some mechanism to check if user already logged in or not... same way how or what I need to check in my app (may be some browser property, auth token or something) to check if user is logged off from google or not?

Comment: Added relevant tags, modified redundant explanation. Added an explicit question to his description.